# No StackTrace in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-standard, blazor

I'm trying to get the stack trace in my Blazor.Shared DLL.

But `Environment.StackTrace` returns an empty string and

`System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(0, true)` returns an empty stack.

Comment: Blazor issues should be discussed on GitHub https://github.com/aspnet/aspnetcore/issues

Comment: @LexLi hardly.  While it's certainly welcome to point out other available resources, answering questions of this sort is literally the whole point of this site.

Comment: Hah, this is great . . . is this you?  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9950. Did you ever get an answer or did you give up?

Comment: Ha! Yep. Quite the runaround. The issue has since been resolved for me.